# Reference Template(?) Widgets in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So lets say in my kv file i do this

```
<BigButton@Button>:
    text: "demo"
    some_other_things: True
```

how do i add this widget in py? this doesnt work:

```
someWidget=self.ids.someWidgetID
TestButton=BigButton(some_other_other_things=False)
someWidget.add_widget(TestButton)
```

It throws a NameError that BigButton isnt defined

Any Help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own Question:
To create this kind of widget you use Factory

```
from kivy.factory import Factory

someParentWidget = self.ids.someParentWidgetID

TestButton = Factory.BigButton()
TestButton.some_other_other_thing=True
someParentWidget.add_widget(TestButton)
```